# COBOL Error Code 18

Tags: cobol

I have an error code 18 in COBOL when I'm trying to write the output to a file. I'm using Micro Focus VS 2012. I have tried everything but it seem doesn't print the output correctly at this time.

```
   ...
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.

       SELECT GRADE-FILE ASSIGN TO 'Grades.txt'.

       SELECT PRINT-FILE ASSIGN TO 'Output.txt'
       ORGANIZATION IS LINE SEQUENTIAL.


   DATA DIVISION.
   FILE SECTION.
   FD GRADE-FILE
      LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD.
   01 GRADE-RECORD.
      05 I-STUDENT PIC X(14).
      05 I-GRADE1  PIC 999.
      05 I-GRADE2  PIC 999.
      05 I-GRADE3  PIC 999.
      05 I-GRADE4  PIC 999.
      05 I-GRADE5  PIC 999.
      05 I-GRADE6  PIC 999.

   FD PRINT-FILE
      LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD.
   01 PRINT-RECORD PIC X(80).


   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
   01 PROGRAM-VARIABLES.
       05 W-AVERAGE  PIC 999V99.
       05 W-EOF-FLAG PIC X VALUE 'N'.

   01 PAGE-TITLE.
       05 PIC X(46) VALUE
       '   S I X   W E E K   G R A D E   R E P O R T'.

   01 HEADING-LINE1.
       05 PIC X(51) VALUE
       ' Student      T e s t    S c o r e s    Average'.

   01 HEADING-LINE2.
       05 PIC X(51) VALUE
       '--------------------------------------------------'.

   01 DETAIL-LINE.
       05                   PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 O-STUDENT         PIC X(14).
       05                   PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 O-GRADE1          PIC ZZ9.
       05                   PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 O-GRADE2          PIC ZZ9.
       05                   PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 O-GRADE3          PIC ZZ9.
       05                   PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 O-GRADE4          PIC ZZ9.
       05                   PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 O-GRADE5          PIC ZZ9.
       05                   PIC X VALUE SPACE.
       05 O-GRADE6          PIC ZZ9.
       05                   PIC X(4) VALUE SPACE.
       05 O-AVERAGE         PIC ZZ9.99.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   10-MAINLINE.
       OPEN INPUT GRADE-FILE
           OUTPUT PRINT-FILE
       PERFORM 20-PRINT-HEADINGS
       PERFORM 30-PROCESS-LOOP
       CLOSE GRADE-FILE
           PRINT-FILE
       STOP RUN.

   20-PRINT-HEADINGS.
       MOVE PAGE-TITLE TO PRINT-RECORD
       WRITE PRINT-RECORD AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE
       MOVE HEADING-LINE1 TO PRINT-RECORD
       WRITE PRINT-RECORD AFTER ADVANCING 3 LINES
       MOVE HEADING-LINE2 TO PRINT-RECORD
       WRITE PRINT-RECORD AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE.

   30-PROCESS-LOOP.
  *    PERFORM 40-READ-RECORD
       READ GRADE-FILE
       PERFORM UNTIL W-EOF-FLAG = 'Y'
           PERFORM 50-COMPUTE-GRADE-AVERAGE
           PERFORM 60-PRINT-DETAIL-LINE
           READ GRADE-FILE
  *        PERFORM 40-READ-RECORD
       END-PERFORM.

  *40-READ-RECORD.
  *    READ GRADE-FILE
  *        AT END MOVE 'Y' TO W-EOF-FLAG.

   50-COMPUTE-GRADE-AVERAGE.
       COMPUTE W-AVERAGE ROUNDED = (I-GRADE1 + I-GRADE2 + I-GRADE3 + I-GRADE4 + I-GRADE5 + I-GRADE6 ) / 6.

   60-PRINT-DETAIL-LINE.
       MOVE SPACES TO DETAIL-LINE
       MOVE I-STUDENT TO O-STUDENT
       MOVE I-GRADE1 TO O-GRADE1
       MOVE I-GRADE2 TO O-GRADE2
       MOVE I-GRADE3 TO O-GRADE3
       MOVE I-GRADE4 TO O-GRADE4
       MOVE I-GRADE5 TO O-GRADE5
       MOVE I-GRADE6 TO O-GRADE6
       MOVE W-AVERAGE TO O-AVERAGE
       WRITE PRINT-RECORD FROM DETAIL-LINE AFTER ADVANCING 1 LINE.

   end program "GradeReport.Program1"

 S I X   W E E K   G R A D E   R E P O R T


 Student      T e s t    S c o r e s    Average
--------------------------------------------------
 KellyAntonetz0 700 500 980 800 650 852    747.00
 obertCain09708 207 907 309 406 2;1 25>    400.67
 Dehaven0810870 940 850 930 892 122 981    785.83
 rmon0760770800 810 750 92; 142 9>1 <1>    816.33
 g0990930890830 940 901 =1> 41= ?82  65    872.50
 06707108408809 6=9 ;52 565 <<0 900 870    924.33
 78052076089Woo 493 9>4 520 760 760 830    734.50
```

Comment: It would be good to specify where the error is raised, e.g, in the OPEN or in the WRITE? also use a FILE STATUS, have separate OPEN for input and output and see what Error 18 means in your compiler.

Comment: You don't show sample input data. The `z0` in the first line of output is suspicious - I'd look at your file-organisation if I were you. The "numeric" data in the report body should give you a clue. The fact that it's unusual to have a student named `obert...` should indicate that your input data isn't being read correctly - from there, it's GIGO. You appear to be reading fixed-length records from a file with variable-length data records.

Comment: EmmadKareem's advice is good and Magoo has spotted something key. You need to show your input records. It seems that the space that should separate the first two elements of the name on the first record is "missing" somehow (COBOL hasn't done it) as are other spaces in the names. Your input data is variable in length, affecting the name field, and that is causing all your other fields to "pull" to the left. Before the COBOL program, "something" has taken all the spaces from your names.

Answer (score 2):

Something prior to your COBOL program has pickled your file by removing all the spaces and shuffling the data to the left.

Your first student shows as `KellyAntonetz` but likely should be `Kelly Antonetz`. Since only one space was removed, the grade data has moved only one place to the left, so the numbers are still recognizable and although the average is a factor of 10 out, it is approximately correct.

It is not actually correct (except for the power of 10) because of that `2` following the `85`. Where did that `2` come from?

It came from the next record, where the first-name should be Robert but you show as `obertCain09708`. The ASCII code for the letter R is X'82'. When treated as a number by COBOL the `8` will be ignored (or will cause a crash when in the trailing byte of a number). Your compiler doesn't cause the code to crash, but does treat the R as the number `2`.

`obertCain` is only 9 bytes out of the 14 you have for the name. The five spaces/blanks which have been "lost" this time cause the numerics to be pulled-left by five bytes. From that point onward, explaining how the output you show fits the presumed input becomes an academic exercise only.

Further support is a reference for what would be a FILE STATUS code of 18 from a Micro Focus compiler, here: http://www.simotime.com/vsmfsk01.htm

Which says, for `18`:

> Read part record error: EOF before EOR or file open in wrong mode
>   (Micro Focus).

Your final record would "finish" before expected, with end-of-file being detected before 32 bytes have been read.

Note that the error is on your *input* file, not your output file.

Losing the spaces in that way can be done in many ways, so I can't guess what you are doing to the file before it gets to the COBOL program, but neither COBOL itself nor your code is doing that.

Take note of Emmad Kareem's comments. Use the `FILE STATUS`. Check the file-status field (define one per file) after each IO, so that you know when a problem occurs, and what the problem is.

Testing the file-status field for 10 on a file you are reading sequentially gives cleaner code than the `AT END` on the `READ`.

Note also that if your program had not crashed there, it would either loop infinitely or crash shortly afterwards. Probably in trying to fix your problem, you have commented-out your use of the "read paragraph" and in that paragraph is the only place you are setting end-of-file.

If you use the file-status instead of AT END, you don't need to define a flag/switch you can use an 88 on the file-status field and have the COBOL run-time set it for you directly, without you having to code it.

Just a couple of points about your DETAIL-LINE.

There is no need to `MOVE SPACE` to it, as you MOVE to each named field, and the (un-named) FILLERs have VALUE SPACE.

You don't *necessarily* need the (un-named) FILLERS. Try this:

```
   01 DETAIL-LINE.
       05 O-STUDENT         PIC BX(14).
       05 O-GRADE1          PIC ZZZ9.
       05 O-GRADE2          PIC ZZZ9.
       05 O-GRADE3          PIC ZZZ9.
       05 O-GRADE4          PIC ZZZ9.
       05 O-GRADE5          PIC ZZZ9.
       05 O-GRADE6          PIC ZZZ9.
       05 O-AVERAGE         PIC Z(6)9.99.
```

If you work with COBOL, you may see this type of thing, so it is good to know. With massive amounts of output there is probably a small performance penalty. You may find it more convenient for "lining-up" output to headings.

Ah. Putting together you non-use of `LINE SEQUENTIAL` for your input file, I predict you have a "script" running some time before the COBOL program which is supposed to remove the record-terminators (whatever those are on your OS) at the end of each logical record, but that you have accidentally removed all `whitespace` from all positions of your record instead.

With `LINE SEQUENTIAL` you can have records of fixed-length which also happen to be "terminated". Unless the exercise specifically includes the removal of the record terminators, just use `LINE SEQUENTIAL`.

If you are supposed to remove the terminators, don't do so for `whitespace` which covers too much (be specific) and also "anchor" the change to the end of the record.